# Very slow SQL queries on varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, indexing

I'll preface this question by stating that I am in no way a SQL expert.

However, I am trying to get a handle on what is happening with our database. We have been using a piece of code that would query a server database which has been working fine for years.

Recently though, we have been getting timeout errors. The database has grown over the years but it is still relatively small (the table in question has about 50 million records).

My suspicion is that the table has gotten too large for our non-professionally set up database to handle. So I tried to run a following simple query on the table SQL Management Studio:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Table] 
WHERE [Variable] = 'NNNNNNNN12'
```

The variable is set up as a `varchar(50)`. This query took 30-60 seconds to complete. That seems like too much to me. We run a similar query on our software with the default timeout of 15 seconds.

Digging into a little bit, I realized that the table did not have a primary key designated. So I made the one but to my surprise it made it slower. The same query now takes about 5 seconds longer.

The next thing I tried was add an index for the `varchar` column but that again made it slower - adding another 10 seconds. Adding a full text index made it even worse with almost a minute response time.

The only thing I've managed to do was make it slower - so I need your help. Am I even on the right track here? Is 30 seconds reasonable for this type of query?  Any other ideas on what I can try?

Comment: Setting up an index on the column that corresponds to "variable" should have solved the problem for that query.  Have you tried using the query analyser (assuming such a thing exists for SQLServer)?

Comment: What does your query plan say? Is it doing a table scan? How fragmented is the table? Does the table have any other really big columns?

Comment: "We run a similar query on our software with the default timeout of 15 seconds" implies your using this for an OLTP process rather than a OLAP process. Is that correct?

Comment: What are the other columns like in your table? Any varchar(MAX) columns? TEXT columns? Try selecting only the `Variable` column instead of all of them. Also try remoting into your server and running the query locally to test if your network is slowing down the return of your resultset. Personally I've found before that my queries were executing in reasonable time but because the resultset was so large SSMS took much longer to retrieve and render the data

Comment: Any reason why you are using Select * and not just selecting the columns you might need?
How's the table structure that you are using? any varbinary columns or varchar(max)?
Try creating a clustered index and then a nonclustered index over the [Variable] column and just select the variable column within the Select statement and share your results

If we are getting a reasonable response with 3 option, you can add the rest of the columns as included columns on the nonclustered index but please be carefull on this as you might have a wider index when you dont need it

Comment: How many rows does your query match? (Is `Variable` unique?) Did you make sure statistics were updated when you added the indexes?

Comment: Make sure the query literal value is a non-unicode value. Since the database field is a varchar, if the query value is a nvarchar it would cause all database values be converted first and no index is used.  Try your select with 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE [Variable] = 'CONVERT(VARCHAR, 'NN12345')' to make sure.

Comment: @JohnD The query cost, if that is what you're referring, is just doing a clustered index scan. The table should not be fragmented at all.  All the columns of the table are fully populated.

Comment: @UpAllNight No varchar(max) columns.  There are 11 columns, 8 of which are varchar(50) and the rest datetime and int.  Selecting only the variable column returns the results instantly, as soon as I add another column to the query it slows back down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the following scripts for some guidance..

```
USE YourDatabase
GO
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
GO
-- A table must have a primary key which implicity will create the clustered index
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CLIX_[Table]_YourPrimaryKey_Or_RowIdentifier ON [Table] (YourPrimaryKey_Or_RowIdentifier)
GO
-- A nonclustered index is needed if we are going to retrieve information using the Variable Column
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table_Variable ON [Table] (Variable)
GO
Select * FROM [dbo].[Table] where [Variable] = 'NN12345'
GO
--Check Results, copy the values from the messages tab to http://www.statisticsparser.com/
GO
Select [Variable] FROM [dbo].[Table] where [Variable] = 'NN12345'
GO
--Check Results, copy the values from the messages tab to http://www.statisticsparser.com/
--Compare the values for logical reads on the two executions
GO
--if you need more columns for the select statement, you can add them as included columns in this way:
GO
DROP INDEX IX_Table_Variable
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table_Variable ON [Table] (Variable) INCLUDE (TheOthersColumns)
GO
--PLEASE make sure you are testing on the development environment prior to move to PROD.
```

Questions to be considered:

- Do I need all the columns during the output result?
- Any Varbinary or varchar(max) sql type during the execution? (slow performance if we have them included)
- Can you add more filters in order to involve more indexes during the execution plan?

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.  Selecting everything was slow but just the indexed column was very fast.  Creating the index with the Include fixed this query. I am not going to create an index with all the columns that are used for the where conditions in the real query and have all the not filtered but returned columns under the include.

Comment: I'm glad to add some value to your question, please mark it as a good answer if that's the case @carbog thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's good you solved the performance problem with index include. If you find the performance problems creeping back, you can try reorganising or rebuilding the indexes.

I had a table of about 10 million rows with clustered index and over time Sql Server 2005 (and 2008 after we upgraded) kept reverting back to using it, even when I created an index as above which included the main columns involved in the `SELECT`. Initially all was good, the execution plan was using the new index, but after a few weeks our queries would start timing out again and we'd find Sql Server was using clustered index scan again.

We never got to the bottom of why it happened but a reliable workaround was to rebuild the indexes and update the statistics.

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.[Table] REBUILD
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.[Table]
```

For us, this was quick - 5 to 10 minutes - but try it on a copy of your production database first to see how long it takes in your case.

Over time, indexes can become fragmented. They start out with the pages corresponding to consecutive keys being physically together and each page is filled up to the FILLFACTOR setting. With inserts or deletes, there may be page splits. Logically related pages are no longer physically together and instead of one page at 100% you have 2 pages at 50% usage. You're jumping around more on the disk to retrieve data and there are more half empty pages to load.

You can check fragmentation with

```
declare @db_id int = db_id('stackoverflow'); 
select db_name(database_id), object_name(object_id), *
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats ( @db_id, null, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED' )
```

The column `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` should be as close to zero as possible for best performance. `avg_page_space_used_in_percent` is the average percentage of available data storage space used in all pages and should be high.

Comment: I assume you tried just `UPDATE STATISTICS` without rebuilding the index in your situation?

Comment: Yes, we tried that first, but it did not make enough of a difference. The timeout was 60 seconds (called through a webservice) and the cluster scan was taking 2-3 minutes when we ran the stored proc on the server. After index rebuild the query ran in less than a second. The table held a `varchar(max)` which contained a PDF, typically 50-150KB, so they would have been stored off page. The solution that solved the problem was to create a new table with the same key and the `varchar(max)` and join it to the original table on the key.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
Select * FROM [dbo].[Table] where [Variable] = 'NN12345'
```

You need an index:

```
create index idx_table_variable on table(variable);
```

Then, there are a few cautions.  The `variable` and constant value need to be of the same type and collation.  So, if you have an index and the above query does not use the index, something else might be going on (such as collation incompatibilities between the table column and the default for the server or database).

Comment: I'm sure this was everyone's first thought, but the OP indicated they already tried adding an index. We don't really have enough information to diagnose beyond that.

Comment: @jpmc26 . . . The OP does not specify what index s/he added and this explains the issue with collations, which can prevent index usage.